# How to show Jqgrid On jquery alert box on double clicking grid rows

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, alert

I have a jqgrid which is displaying records locally..Now as per my need i have to show  one more jqgrid in jquery alert box on double clicking jqgrid row by taking column value of that particular row and pulling data from database...Is there any method by which i can achieve this ...

This is my piece of code..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#go").click(function () {
    $("#gridId").GridUnload();
    gridload();
});
```

Any help will be highly appreciated..
Thanks in advance...

Comment: create a fiddle please

Comment: @DeepSharma Sir i have to show a new jqgrid on new window based on values of the row on double click of jqgrid row..Sorry sir i dont know to create fiddle.

Comment: @vikas There is no way to natively show a jqGrid (or any html for that matter) inside an alert box. Maybe you are referring to a jQuery UI Dialog?

Comment: @FastTrack yes sir i mean the same Jquery ui dialogue...